# MySql Join three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have join three table into one table but there different column name but same value.

**Student Table**

```
-------------
CV_id    name
-------------
LC001     ali
LC002     ahmed
LC003     john
LC004     king
```

**Course Table**

```
-------------
Us_id    name
-------------
LC001     physic
LC002     maths
LC003     computer
LC004     chemistry
```

**Bridge**

```
-------------
sid    CV_cid
-------------
ti     LC001
ni     LC002
df     LC003
ed     LC004
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: thnx.here i have edit

Comment: Please read about JOIN and UNION. Using one of them you can get desired output.

Comment: what is your expected result

Comment: please refer this 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/qtQ08.png

Comment: @Kasun - Is this question still open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to join by the `id` fields:

```
select s.name student_name, c.name course_name, b.sid from student s
join course c
on c.us_id = s.cv_id
join bridge b
on b.cv_id = s.cv_id
```

Here is some information about [SQL joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: thnx.have to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to achieve your result

```
SELECT ST.CV_id, ST.name, CO.name, BR.`sid`
FROM Student ST
INNER JOIN Course CO ON CO.Us_id = ST.CV_id
INNER JOIN Bridge BR ON BR.CV_cid = ST.CV_id
```

Comment: @Kasun: Based on the tables only the query written. Can you share the expected result.

Comment: have to get all three table info into one table based on "LC0" id

Comment: @Kasun, in case if you want to filter by only one id, add in the last `WHERE ST.CV_id = 'LC001'`

Comment: @Kasun Is the query above didn't give your expected result? You can add/remove the column names in the SELECT as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are joining the table on 1st column as the primary key.

`SELECT t1.col, t2.col, t3.col FROM tbl1 
join tbl2 ON tbl1.pk = tbl2.pk 
join tbl3 ON tbl2.pk = tbl3.pk`

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN USE JOIN

```
SELECT s.CV_id, s.name, c.name, b.sid
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Course c ON c.Us_id = s.CV_id
INNER JOIN Bridge b ON b.CV_cid = s.CV_id
```